# Book/tutorial recommendations: acquiring math-oriented reading proficiency in German

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, learning, mathematical-german

I'm interested in others' suggestions/recommendations for resources to help me acquire reading proficiency (of current math literature, as well as classic math texts) in German.

I realize that German has evolved as a language, so ideally, the resource(s) I'm looking for take that into account, or else perhaps I'll need a number of resources to accomplish such proficiency. I suspect I'll need to include multiple resources (in multiple forms) in my efforts to acquire the level of reading proficiency I'd like to have.

I do like "hard copy" material, at least in part, from which to study. But I'm also very open to suggested websites, multimedia packages, etc.

In part, I'd like to acquire reading proficiency in German to meet a degree requirement, but as a native English speaker, I would also like to be able to study directly from significant original German sources.

Finally, there's no doubt that a sound/solid reference/translation dictionary (or two or three!) will be indispensable, as well.  Any recommendations for such will be greatly appreciated, keeping in mind that my aim is to be proficient in reading *mathematically-oriented* German literature (though I've no objections to expanding from this base!).

Comment: [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/) is a very good and mostly reliable online dictionary (German/English/French/Spanish/Italian/Chinese/Russian) I can only vouch for the first four and I'm rather happy with the results. Mathematical words are not covered very well, though.

Comment: There is also a new sister-forum exclusively for German: http://german.stackexchange.com/ - it is not exclusively for math-oriented German but there are many well qualified persons that are eager to answer your questions (me included :-)

Comment: There's this book by Schubert Topology https://g.co/kgs/rj3PnT.   A friend gave it to me at Berkeley.   I enjoyed reading it a little bit;   and eventually passed the German language exam for the Ph d program at ucla...  of course,  i also took two semesters of german...  and travelled to Germany...

Comment: This question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: It was at the time of it's posting.  You can't judge posts from 11-12 years ago, in the manner we have since 2020.  And reference requests are not forbidden, when context is provided.  Besides, I don't gain rep from it, nor do any of the answerers.  Look up "Community Wiki"?

Answer (score 19):

Landau's Grundlagen der Analysis in the AMS edition comes with a "complete German-English vocabulary", this sounds ideal for your purposes.

Comment: This does sound good: the math review even mentions it is targeted to beginning readers of mathematical German: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=109776

Comment: Eine gute empfehlung

Answer (score 14):

After searching in google books I found a book called [German-English Mathematical Vocabulary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CJGI6). It appears to be out of print but nevertheless can be bought used for just a few dollars in Amazon.

I just checked my University library and they have it so tomorrow I will check it out to see what it has to offer. I will report back after looking at the book to add something about it.

Also this German-English [math dictionary](http://mathdict.chitanka.info/en/de-en/) might be useful, it even comes with links to the corresponding Wikipedia articles for each concept.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that the second link isn't working at the moment, here is a [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160829205656/http://mathdict.chitanka.info/en/de-en/e). I searched a bit, but I did not find whether this dictionary was moved to some other URL.

Answer (score 4):

I find it helpful to translate papers I sort of know and still care about.  If you have a favorite course you've taken and understood, get a german textbook for the course and translate a section or work some of the exercises.  If you type up the exercises, make sure to type up the original question in German and English (and your answer in English).

If you like algebra, and you might try one of the [algebra books on SpringerLink](https://link.springer.com/search?query=algebra&facet-language=%22De%22&facet-content-type=%22Book%22).

If you like solving exercises, then you can just go to course webpages and download their homework.  For instance: [algebraic number theory I](https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/Vorl/zt1.html), [linear algebra](https://web.archive.org/web/20130408170108/http://www2.math.rwth-aachen.de:8055/exquery.html), [etc.](https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/current_de.html)

Comment: These are great suggestions..."Go directly to the source, so to speak," (and extend my familiarity with English to German...). Nice.

Answer (score 3):

Just for looking up German-English vocabulary in particular for math terms, I would recommend [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/). I use it the same way: German -> English.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a bit late, but I just saw by chance that the math department of Princeton has a [list of German words](http://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/germanwords.html) online, seemingly for people who want to read German math papers.

Comment: Really, a poor collection:)

Answer (score 2):

If your focus includes number theory, then Landau's classic *Handbuch Der Lehre Von Der Verteilung Der Primzahlen* is an excellent choice. You can easily find a hard copy and/or read it online, for example, at [University of Michigan Historical Math Collection](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=umhistmath;idno=ABV2766.0002.001)