# Reference: Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I want to read a book on group theory "Endliche Gruppen I" by Huppert, Blackburn etc. I do not know, whether it is translated in English. Can one suggest a way for this- "Online Mathematics dictionary, German to English", or whether book translated in English, or any other?

Comment: Did you try to search?! [This one](http://books.google.com/books?id=UU9btwAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Norman+Blackburn%22&hl=en&ei=lkZwTuvTC8Xc4QSVupWpCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw) doesn't have the "I" in the title, but since [this one](http://books.google.com/books/about/Finite_groups_II.html?id=Nv7uAAAAMAAJ) has the "II", I presume the other one must be volume I?

Comment: @joriki: I saw the title in Bibliographies. Vol. II is in English. But searching vol. 1.

Comment: Are you saying the first one I linked to isn't Vol. I? Then what is it?

Comment: It is not showing volumes number; sorry,  I couldn't see whether this a combined volume or volume I.

Comment: When you've already found partial information and you want to complete it, it's a good idea to tell people what you already know and what's still missing; otherwise they a) go and find it out themselves, which is a waste of their time, and b) tell you things you already know, which is a waste of both their and your time.

Comment: Let me just mention that, at present, most PhD programs require their students to demonstrate proficiency in reading math in at least one if not two foreign languages; German will essentially always be an acceptable choice.  So even if it's not the quickest way, it might be a good idea to translate this yourself just for the practice.

Comment: Volume I, called "Endliche Gruppen" is by Huppert alone, and is (I believe) only available in German. That is a very complete basic textbook in group theory. Volumes II and III are in English and are by Huppert and Blackburn. They are more specialized and cover topics like general representation theory.

Comment: Does anyone know why Vol. II and III were translated but Vol. I was not? I wondered this back in college when I first looked at one of these books.

Comment: @KCd I think II and III were written in English with Norman Blackburn (not even sure they exist in German), whereas the first was just by Huppert.

Comment: @user3296: Where are the universities you talk about? The concept of a second language was never discussed when I was applying for my PhD (in the UK), and of the students in my office who did their undergrads in English-speaking universities none of them can do/read maths in any other languages...

Comment: It's almost a universal requirement here in the United States, and I'd assumed that the requirement had come from Britain in the first place.  Certainly it was only 40 of 50 years ago that a practicing mathematician would *have* to read French or German or both, depending on the field, just to stay afloat.

Comment: @Kcd: mt_ is right; II and III were originally written in English.  I have often fantasized about translating I into English, but it is such a monstrous book it would take a long time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46313/book-tutorial-recommendations-acquiring-math-oriented-reading-proficiency-in-ger/).
Here are two German-English mathematical dictionaries:

http://www.henked.de/maple/dictionary.htm

http://www.math.uni-goettingen.de/baule/wbuch.html

Offline there's a Langenschiedt English/German/French/Russian mathematical dictionary ISBN 3861170744, and Landau's Grundlagen der Analysis in the AMS edition comes with a "complete German-English vocabulary" that could be helpful.  I don't think there is an English translation of Endliche Gruppen I.

Comment: Thanks! Both links are useful.